# Problems with rendering and Trees

Tags: rendering, vertices, faces, polycount

I've recently gotten into the architectural angle of 3D and naturally, I wanted some nature (Plants, grass, trees, bushes and so on). But when I got to it and downloaded some tree models I had a hard time setting up a scene. Very laggy and render times well over the 1-hour mark with only a few trees and sometimes I couldn't even render because of lack of memory.

How do I fix this? I want a background covered in trees and forest like environment so there are no "loose ends" (endless space in the background)

Comment: Do Archviz background trees need to be real geometry? They could be part of a b/g HDR, or plates?

Comment: They do not necessarily need to be geometry but I have had some experiments with the following and couldn't really get it to work. Do you have any tips or ways to implement it?

Comment: Maybe you could refine the question: "I need no render-time trees to achieve  effect X in shots like Y in  style Z" ? or something like that, with illustration?  There will be folks here who are slicker and quicker at archviz than me, I'm sure..

Comment: I had never heard the word Archviz before and it greatly helped my search parameter. If I can't find an answer I will try and make a new question. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad that helps! ..You could just edit this question.. if that's easier